# Trying to understand / troubleshoot intersection behavior of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, intersection

I'm trying to calculate the percent of intersection between two polygons using PostGIS.

I was able to do so successfully for 90% of my polygons, but about 1500 have very unexpected values.  I extracted one of these cases to examine the behavior.

The orange polygon resides w/in the purple polygons so the proportion should be near 100%.

[image: the two polygons]

However, after running:

```
UPDATE orange 
SET pct_undevelopable = ST_Area(ST_Intersection(orange.geom, purple.geom)) / ST_Area(orange.geom)
FROM purple WHERE ST_Intersects(orange.geom, purple.geom);
```

I get the value for percent of area of intersection as: 0.000828452095134945

So I inspected the intersection part of the query and found that I got 3 rows as geometry outputs.

I exported all three as individual shapefiles: one simply doesn't work... I tried to open it in QGIS and ArcGIS and I also tried in CSV format for QGIS, no luck.

And two polygons.

Polygon 1 is what I imagine PostGIS is calculating percent of intersection from: [image]

Polygon 2 is what I imagine I would like PostGIS to calculate it from:
[image]

I would love it if anyone can 
1) explain what is going on (especially with the weird non functioning intersection geometry) and

2) how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting strange results because you have more than one row in `purple` that joins to `orange` on the condition `ST_Intersects(purple.geom, orange.geom)`.  In PostgreSQL, this produces undefined behaviour.  From the PostgreSQL docs on [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html):

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

One way around this issue is to use a subquery to aggregate the sum of the overlap areas:

```
UPDATE orange 
SET pct_undevelopable = 
    (SELECT sum(ST_Area(ST_Intersection(orange.geom, purple.geom))) 
     FROM purple WHERE ST_Intersects(orange.geom, purple.geom))
     / ST_Area(orange.geom);
```

Comment: Another option might be to Union your purple geometries (http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Union.html)

Comment: @BradHards I tried the Union query thank you, but it added a significant amount of time to the query.  It was taking 30 minutes before, with bastions solution 45 minutes, with a union, 4 hours.